# returning the index name from JSON in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Imagine we have this JSON:

```
{ "A" : {"A1": "1" } }
```

How can I extract the actual index A1 ?
So that I can use it in JS like:

```
var index = "A1";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*edit* — in case you mean, "How can I extract the **value** at index A1", then you'd just use the dot or bracket operators:

```
var value = object.A.A1;
```

or

```
var index = "A1";
var value = object.A[index];
```

Else see below.

---

You can iterate through the property names of an object with the `for ... in` loop:

```
for (var propertyName in object) {
  // ...
}
```

The loop will also include properties from the prototype chain, so you can avoid that (if you want) with a function called `hasOwnProperty`:

```
for (var name in object) {
  if (object.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    // really is a local property
  }
}
```

Newer browsers support a way to get the property names as an array:

```
var names = Object.keys( yourObject );
```

That list will only include "own" properties; that is, those for which `hasOwnProperty()` would return `true`.

Finally, there are ways that properties can be defined such that they're not "enumerable".  Usually when that's done, you would generally *not* want to see them in `for ... in` anyway.